# If events are at least measure $1/2$ is there an experiment in infinitely many of them?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \Gamma, \mathbb{P})$ and a sequence of events $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \Gamma$. If $\mathbb{P}(A_i) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, is it true that there is $\omega \in \Omega$ that is in infinitely many sets $A_i$?

(The question here is stated out of context, hence the strange claim regarding a set of possibly zero measure.)

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question (hazard of making too many guesses about context).

Comment: Now I'm interested in the answer too!

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks for your comment. This is a part of a longer proof and I'm trying to figure out whether these conditions are, stated in abstract, enough to guarantee the existence of the element $\omega$ or if the argument relies on some external fact that's found between the lines earlier in the proof. In context, the set $\Omega$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, $\Gamma$ is Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathbb{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure and the sets $A_i$ are preimages $f^{-1}(-\infty, a_i)$.

Comment: So a suitable answer would either prove the claim from the information given, or find a counterexample (thus saying you should look for something "between the lines earlier in the proof").

Comment: Yes, if a sequence of events $A_i$ that contradicts the claim above can be constructed, there has to be some piece of additional information in the specific situation I'm dealing with that produces the result. If such counterexample exists, it could also be valuable hint of where to look. The book I'm reading presents the proofs in a rather concise form :)

Comment: Actually it is not true. Counterexample: $A_i=A_1$ for every $i$. Then there are no infinitely many sets $A_i$. There is only one (and infinitely many indices $i$). Don't take this nitpicking too serious, though :).

Comment: @drhab: Hah, that's were we leave math and enter philosophy. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $1_{\liminf B_n}=\liminf1_{B_n}$ for any sequence $(B_n)_n$.

With Fatou's lemma it can be shown that:$$1-P(\liminf A_n^{\complement})=1-\int\liminf1_{A_n^{\complement}}\geq1-\liminf\int1_{A_n^{\complement}}=1-\liminf P(A_n^{\complement})$$or equivalently:$$P(\limsup A_n)\geq\limsup P(A_n)$$

Comment: Good ol reverse Fatou's lemma works perfectly here. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Without overlooking the effort by others that answered, this is super elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact $A_i$ occurs infinitely often with probability at least $1/2.$ Suppose not; then the event $B_n$ that at most $n$ of the events $A_i$ occur has probability $p>1/2$ for sufficiently large $n.$ But the expected number of $A_i$ that occur in this event is still infinite - each $i$ contributes $p-1/2$ - a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is claiming. Do you mean to imply (for example) that an infinite number of the events in the sequence $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ are equal to $A_1$? This seems to be contradicted by a sequence of events over $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $A_i = [1/2^i, 1/2+1/2^i].$

Comment: @DavidK: “$A_i$ infinitely often” is the set the question is asking for; it can be described as the lim sup of $A_i$, or equivalently the set of $\omega$ such that there are infinitely many $i$ with $\omega\in A_i.$